# Select column description from Netezza

Tags: get, comments, netezza, col

I'm trying to get the description of the columns in Netezza but nothing comes up. In a table, I can get the description `select TABLENAME,DESCRIPTION from _v_table;` but how do I get the description of the columns?

Answer (score 0):

You need to access a different source - _v_table are at a more ganular level (table) - try this:

```
SELECT *
    FROM _V_RELATION_COLUMN
    where DESCRIPTION is not null
```